# L'«Europe(-)puissance » : modèle, détails ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, mots-composés, trait-d-union, politique

Un haut représentant de l'Union européenne donne une opinion dans [LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/debats/opinions/2022-07-06/moscou-devra-choisir-entre-le-beurre-et-les-canons.php) où il dit « C’est pourquoi le passage à une **Europe-puissance**, que j’appelle de mes vœux depuis le début de mon mandat, est un impératif » (Josep Borrell Fontelles, je souligne). Assurément le terme est [protéiforme](https://theconversation.com/de-quoi-leurope-puissance-est-elle-le-nom-148704) mais indépendamment de tout ce qu'il peut vouloir dire, j'aimerais comprendre sur quel modèle il est construit.

- Ai-je bien compris que le terme *Europe* est comme un préfixe qui
  qualifie *puissance* : peut-on remanier le terme en une phrase avec
  un nom, un adjectif et une préposition qui confirme ou infirme cette
  affirmation ; a-t-on d'autres exemples notables où *Europe* est ainsi employé ?
- Évite-t-on de construire ça avec [*euro-*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_(homonymie)) vu la monnaie et le sport ?
- Est-il plus fréquent d'avoir avec ou sans le trait d'union et est-ce un
  signe de lexicalisation ; le terme est-il de notoriété publique ?

Answer (score 2):

> ([La Tribune, Christian Lequesne, Sciences Politiques](https://www.latribune.fr/opinions/tribunes/europe-puissance-un-enjeu-de-la-campagne-presidentielle-francaise-913122.html))  Qu'entend-on par « Europe puissance » ?
>
> Le thème de l'« Europe puissance » a été inventé en France. Il est toujours difficile de retracer la genèse exacte d'un concept utilisé dans le discours politique. Mais on en attribue généralement la paternité à Jean François-Poncet, qui fut ministre des Affaires étrangères de Valéry Giscard d'Estaing de 1978 à 1981. Le thème a été ensuite repris par de nombreux responsables politiques français. Il visait à souligner que l'Europe devait être une puissance militaire, parce que le continent ne pouvait pas dépendre uniquement de la garantie de sécurité des États-Unis.

1/ Il ne s'agit pas d'une construction sur la base d'une racine (qui serait « puissance ») modifiée par un préfixe (qui serait « Europe »), mais d'un nom composé. On peut donner un équivalent syntaxique sur le modèle de nombreux mots composés, dont voici quelques exemples.

- *acteur chanteur* un acteur qui est aussi un chanteur
- *oiseau-mouche*  un oiseau qui est aussi une mouche
- *question piège* une question qui est aussi un piège

La différence entre ces termes et « Europe puissance » (aussi « Europe-puissance ») n'est que dans le nombre de référents, qui dans le cas de ce dernier terme est plutôt restreint. On peut parler d'une Europe-puissance démocratique, d'une europe-puissance autocratique, etc. et on peut même spécialiser ce terme à une réalisation particulière du concept. Dans tous les cas il s'agit d'une *conception de l'Europe politique* (fédération, union quelconque, et toute autre possibilité de groupement comme par exemple sur le modèle de l'empire (l'Europe de Charlemagne)) qui est en même temps *une puissance militaire* (pour ne s'arrêter que sur l'idée essentielle, les autres étant loin d'avoir détourné ce terme de son but premier). Il n'existe pas de référents  dans l'histoire auxquels on aurait appliqué ce terme vu qu'il est de récente origine (Les Europes de Napoléon et de Hitler n'ont eu qu'une très courte durée, mais en essence on pourrait les appeler des Europes-puissance). Ce terme n'a pour l'instant essentiellement qu'un seul référent ; c'est cet élément fictif et mal défini que certains politiciens considèrent comme étant le modèle souhaitable d'une Europe du  futur politiquement et économiquement unie.

Des exemples d'emploi similaire du mot « Europe » doivent être rares ; je n'en connait pas.

Il n'y a pas de remaniement simple qui soit un équivalent exact ; « Europe de la puissance militaire » semble être ce qu'il y aurait de plus approchant ; toute explication,  avant que l'on ait pu dire beaucoup, déborde dans le domaine de la  politique.

-- L'Europe de la puissance militaire ?

-- Une Europe qui est une puissance militaire ?

*Une définition qui cerne plus ou moins bien le concept d'« Europe-puissance »*

Europe-puissance : L'union politicoéconomique de l'Europe qui prévoit en tant que l'une  des bases de cette union  la puissance militaire de l'union (Cela n'explique toujours pas comment cette puissance est envisagée (force militaire commune ou alliance de puissances militaires individuelles)).

Le même problème existe pour des quantités de telles formations ; par exemple, l'oiseau-mouche n'est pas réellement un oiseau qui soit aussi une mouche, c'est plutôt un oiseau qui par son comportement rappelle la mouche (vol bourdonnant et rapide).

2/ Non, on ne devrait pas associer « Europe » à « euro- » dans cette construction. « Eurovision » signifie « télévision à l'échelle de l'Europe, télévision visible dans toute l'europe » ; on a dans ce cas une construction sur le modèle « élément formant | racine » (même principe en anglais, même forme du mot (eurovision)); dans ces constructions l'élément central est la racine alors que dans les mots composés c'est le premier élément qui est central.

3/ L'omission du trait d'union est un peu plus fréquente.

[image]

**Note** En Allemand la traduction est soit « MachtEuropa »  soit « Europa der Macht » (génitif « der Macht » du féminin « die Macht ») ; comme « Europa » est le mot central en allemend, « Europe » l'est en français ; on  retrouve en français dans le terme « Europe des lumières » la même construction que celle utilisant le génitif. Selon ce second modèle allemend on peut s'interroger sur la validité du remaniement « Europe de la puissance ». Attention cependant, le terme « Europe Lumières » n'existe pas et  ne semble pas décrire le phénomème dont il est question dans « Europe des lumières ».
En anglais, on trouve un peu de tout (ce qui semblerait indiquer que ce terme n'est pas bien compris), et même « euro-power », ce qui contredit l'analyse que je mentionne ci-dessus.

Anglais  : powerful Europe, Europe as a political and military power, a political power in the world, Europe as a power, …